# Transferring bookmarks to iPad

Tags: file-transfer, bookmarks, ipad

I would like to know some of the options available to me to transfer my Firefox bookmarks from a laptop running Linux into my iPad. I do not have access to an English based Windows computer or to a Mac.

Comment: You want the bookmarks to be in Safari?

Comment: Yes, the built in browser

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Sync should work fine for that. Have a look at this tutorial:

http://browsers.about.com/od/firef2/ss/Firefox-Sync-Between-Windows-And-The-iPad.htm